# telnetlib errors with read_until

Tags: python

I'm very new to python scripting, but I thought I would give it a go to see if I can automate a few simple tasks I preform regularly over Telnet.

I found a basic python telnet script:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

This 'seems' to work, but returns nothing to the console. Since the login process takes a few seconds, I figure it's just going too fast & needs to wait for the user prompt. So I tried adding this.

```
tn.read_until(">")
```

It does not work... I get this error

```
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    tn.read_until(">")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 319, in read_until
    return self.read_very_lazy()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 395, in read_very_lazy
    raise EOFError, 'telnet connection closed'
EOFError: telnet connection closed
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple... but the solution seems to be alluding me. Any input will be highly appreciated!

Comment: maybe you need to send `\r\n` instead of `\n`, you can confirm with wireshark

Comment: This did it! I replaced \n with \r and it seems to be working a treat now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use another line separator depending on the platform. try `\r` or `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952514/telnetlib-python-example) link - it may help you out. I guess you may want to specify

```
tn.write("vt100\n")
```

before printing out anything.